# How to extract a substring by inverse pattern with R?

Tags: r, regex, string

I trying to extract a substring by pattern using gsub() R function.

```
# Example: extracting "7 years" substring.
string <- "Psychologist - 7 years on the website, online"
gsub(pattern="[0-9]+\\s+\\w+", replacement="", string)`

`[1] "Psychologist -  on the website, online"
```

As you can see, it's easy to exlude needed substring using gsub(), but I need to inverse the result and getting "7 years" only.
I think about using "^", something like that:

`gsub(pattern="[^[0-9]+\\s+\\w+]", replacement="", string)`

Please, could anyone help me with correct regexp pattern?

Comment: Guys, can you please to explain me why do you using "\\1" in 'replacement="\\1"'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use

```
sub(pattern=".*?([0-9]+\\s+\\w+).*", replacement="\\1", string)
```

See [this R demo](https://ideone.com/YiuJQK).

**Details**

- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `([0-9]+\\s+\\w+)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
  - `\\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
  - `\\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `.*` - the rest of the string (any 0+ chars, as many as possible)

The `\1` in the replacement replaces with the contents of Group 1.

Comment: It's working. What does it mean "\\1" in "replacement" argument?
Sorry for first comment :)

Comment: @Michael *The `\1` in the replacement replaces with the contents of Group 1*. `\1` is a [replacement backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html).

Answer (score 4):

You could use the opposite of `\d`, which is `\D` in `R`:

```
string <- "Psychologist - 7 years on the website, online"
sub(pattern = "\\D*(\\d+\\s+\\w+).*", replacement = "\\1", string)
# [1] "7 years"
```

`\D*` means: no digits as long as possible, the rest is captured in a group and then replaces the complete string.

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/EOoGK3/2).

Comment: Thanks. Good solution.